# Testing Spring MVC API: No qualifying bean found

Tags: java, spring

I have the following structure of by Spring MVC API with a single end-point `getAnnotation`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    @Bean
    public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}


@Service
public class MyAnalyzerImpl implements MyAnalyzer
{

    @Autowired
    public MyAnalyzerImpl() {}

    @Override
    public Annotations getAnnotation(MyRequest request)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface MyAnalyzer {
    Annotations getAnnotation(MyRequest request);
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/thisapi/{id}")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("MyAnalysis")
    MyAnalyzer myAnalyzer;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAnnotation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Annotations getAnnotation(@PathVariable String docId,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "document", defaultValue = "{'id':'1','title':'bla-bla'}") String text) {
        MysRequest myRequest = new MyRequest(MyRequest.TYPE_ANNOTATION, text);
        return myAnalyzer.getAnnotation(myRequest);
    }
}
```

To test the API, I firstly created `src/test/java/MyAnalyzerImplTest.java` and was able to successfully execute it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyAnalyzerImplTest {

    private MyAnalyzerImpl myAnalyzer;
    private String sampleText;

    @Test
    public void testEndpoint() throws Exception {
        MyRequest request = new MyRequest(  MyRequest.TYPE_ANNOTATION,
                                                    "1",
                                                    sampleText
                                                 );
        Annotations results = myAnalyzer.getAnnotation(request);
        Assert.assertTrue("This " + results.getPayload().getWords().size() + ") " +
                "should be greater than 0", results.getPayload().getWords().size() > 0);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        myAnalyzer = new MyAnalyzerImpl();
        File f = new File("src/test/resources/texsts/text.json");
        if (f.exists()){
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/texts/text.json");
            samplePublication = IOUtils.toString(is);
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

}
```

Now I want to run `Application.java` to launch API at the address `http://localhost:8080`. I get the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'myController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'myAnalyzer': No qualifying bean of type
>   [org.api.thistool.MyAnalyzer] found for dependency
>   [org.api.thistool.MyAnalyzer]: expected at least 1 bean which
>   qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=MyAnalysis)};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [org.api.thistool.MyAnalyzer] found for
>   dependency [org.api.thistool.MyAnalyzer]: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=MyAnalysis)}

Just in case I also provide the RAML file.

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: MY API
version: v1
baseUri: http://localhost:8080
resourceTypes:
  - annotate-type:
      description: Bla-bla
      get:
        description: bla-bla
        queryParameters:
          text:
            description: json of a document
            type: string
            required: true
            default: "{'id':'1','title':'bla-bla'}"
        responses:
          200:
            body:
              application/json:
                example: |
                  {
                    "words": "['aaa', 'bbb']"
                  }
/thisapi:
    /{id}/getAnnotation:
        type:
          annotate-type:
        uriParameters:
          id:
            description: document id
            type: string
```

Comment: Spring cannot autowire dependency for "MyAnalyzer" because it cannot find a bean with id "MyAnalysis". If there's only a single bean of that type in the context you can remove the @Qualifier("MyAnalysis"). If there is multiple beans of type MyAnalysis add proper @Qualifier for MyAnalyzerImpl

Comment: @jp86: Do you mean I should use `@Autowired
    MyAnalyzer myAnalyzer;` instead of `@Autowired
    @Qualifier("MyAnalysis")
    MyAnalyzer myAnalyzer;`?

Comment: Yes, it should help. I'll try to explain: Your controller needs a _single_ bean of type MyAnalyzer so you're using `@Autowired` on that dependency. This will instruct spring to look up a bean of that type in the context and inject it automatically. When you also declare the `@Qualifier` it will limit the scan to bean with that id, in this case "MyAnalysis". When application starts `MyAnalyzerImpl` will (by default) get the bean id "myAnalyzerImpl" without further instruction, and hence you see the error of "unsatisfied dependency expressed..." when dependencies are being autowired.

Comment: @jp86: Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: np, tell me if it helped.

Comment: @jp86: It now says: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument: public org.api.thistool.MyAnalyzerImpl()`

Comment: @jp86: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument: public org.api.thistool.MyAnalyzerImpl()`

Comment: that's a different error. Remove the `@Autowired` from `MyAnalyzerImpl` constructor. In fact, remove the whole constructor.

Comment: @jp86: I removed it. Now everything works. Thanks.

Comment: good to hear, wrapped it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, original error was due to the use of invalid qualifier `@Qualifier("MyAnalysis")`. No bean for id "MyAnalysis" is present in the context. Since there's only one suitable implementation using additional `@Qualifier` is useless.

Second error was because of the invalid use of `@Autowired` with constructor. Similiar issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683282/java-lang-illegalstateexception-autowired-annotation-requires-at-least-one-argu)